# "At the corner of the bar" or "In the corner of the bar"?

Tags: word-choice

By bar, I mean the wooden rectangle (the counter) not the establishment. In that case, should I say, "to sit at the corner of the bar" or "to sit in the corner of the bar"?

Comment: By *wooden rectangle*, do you mean the counter where drinks are served, or the room in which it is located (and often called a *saloon bar*)?

Comment: @Mick the counter.

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't sit *in* a wooden rectangle would you?  You might sit *in* an establishment.  So you would sit *at* the bar.  To answer your question the prepositional phrase you are looking for is "to sit at a corner of the bar" as in:

> The place was so crowded I had to sit at an uncomfortable corner of the bar.

as opposed to:

> The place was so crowded I had to sit in a dark corner of the bar.

Comment: I think it sounds more idiomatic to say "at **the** corner of the bar", even if there are multiple corners.

Comment: I don't know of any idiomatic expressions like this.